# sort array while preserving indexes

Tags: php, arrays

I need to convert

```
array(  
    '0' => 'z1',    
    '1' => 'Z10', 
    '2' => 'z12', 
    '3' => 'Z2', 
    '4' => 'z3', )
```

into

```
array(
    '0' => 'z1',
    '3' => 'Z2',
    '4' => 'z3',
    '1' => 'Z10',
    '2' => 'z12',
)
```

**Without using asort**. My insert method is not inserting anything into my array what am i doing wrong? P.S is there a  better way then doing 2 loops? 1 to go through array then another to loop for position to insert at?

P.S i know it's easy with asort.

```
<?php
    $arr = array(
        '0' => 'z1',
        '1' => 'Z10',
        '2' => 'z12',
        '3' => 'Z2',
        '4' => 'z3',
    );


    $new_arr = array();
    $temp = array();

    foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
    {


        if(empty($new_arr))
        {
        $new_arr[$key] = $value;
        }

        else
        {
            if(sanitizeValue($new_arr[$key-1]) > sanitizeValue($value))
            {
                foreach($new_arr as $key_p => $value_p)
                {

                    if(sanitizeValue($value) < sanitizeValue($value_p))
                    {
                        insert($new_arr, $key_p, array($key=>$value));
                    }




                }



            }
            else
            {
            $new_arr[$key] = $value;
            }

        }


    }


     function insert($array, $index, $val)
       {

          $temp = array(); // this temp array will hold the value 
          $size = count($array); //because I am going to use this more than one time
         //echo $size; echo $index;

           if (!is_int($index) || $index < 0 || $index > $size)
           {
               return -1;
           }
           else
           {
               $temp   = array_slice($array, 0, $index);
               $temp[] = $val;
               return array_merge($temp, array_slice($array, $index, $size));
           }
       }


    function sanitizeValue($str)
    {
    $str = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    return $str;
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($new_arr);
    echo '</pre>';

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you need to sort an array you should checking the manual page for [Sorting Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php), it's got a great table which helps you identify which sort function to use.

In this case, you want to use `uasort()` to sort by value but keep the keys, and use `strnatcasecmp()` to sort the values using a "natural" (human style) sorting method, which will allow you to put 10 after 1, 2 and 3 instead of it being added after 1 by default, in a case-insensitive way (which allows the difference between z1 and Z10 etc.

[Example:](https://eval.in/306237)

```
uasort($example, function($a, $b) {
    return strnatcasecmp($a, $b);
});

Array
(
    [0] => z1
    [3] => Z2
    [4] => z3
    [1] => Z10
    [2] => z12
)
```

Comment: The only question now is if OP can't use asort, but all other sort functions or non of them

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that's up to him - however I could never condone rewriting the PHP wheel when not required!